# remove fragment not work after addToBackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

When I start a fragment and add to BackStack , then it can not be remove by FragmentTransaction.remove(),add like this:

```java
mManager.beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragment_container, new FB(), "B")
        .addToBackStack("addB")
        .commit();
```

here is remove code:

```
 FB fb = (FB) mManager.findFragmentByTag("B");
        if (fb != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = mManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(fb);
            ft.detach(fb);
            ft.addToBackStack("removeB");
            ft.commit();
        } else {
            showToast("B is not exist");
        }
```

after first time I remove the Fragment B, I still could get Fragment B by

`FB fb = (FB) mManager.findFragmentByTag("B")`

and `onDestory()` `onPause()` `onDetach()` are not work too.

How could I know whether the Fragment B is removed ?

Follow these steps can cause an Exception:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: FB{424365e0 #0 id=0x7f0c004f B}`

steps:

```
addB -> removeB -> removeB -> onBackPressed();
```